# Interpreting ACF and Partial ACF Plots in R

Tags: time-series, interpretation, autocorrelation, acf-pacf

I have a time series with the following ACF and Partial ACF plots; however, I am a little confused on how to interpret these.

I called the following commends:

```
acf(x_values)
pacf(x_values)
```

I believe I can use the $x$-values of my data instead of the residuals. Is that correct?

My thoughts:

1. The ACF plot shows that the model does a satisfactory job based on the autocorrelation. It is clear that lags $l = 0, 1, 2$ are significant with a couple other lags in the distance (is this a result of cyclical behavior???).
2. The PACF plot shows more of a weekly cyclical pattern, as each observation refers to one day.

Is what I am saying above correct? Am I producing and interpreting these plots correctly?

[image]

Comment: Have you read through the many existing threads on this that already exist on the site?  Did none of them shed any light on this?

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica yes and my plots are slightly different than the others

Comment: (1) I would not try to interpret barely significant autocorrelations at lags greater than one or two in the first plot. (2) I'm not sure I'm seeing a "weekly" pattern in the second plot, but autocorrelation seems to disappear for lags beyond ten. // You should read related pages as @gung suggests.